# Why IPv5 was never used?

Tags: ip, protocols, ipv4, qos

Just wondering why IPv5 was never used? It's based on ST-II right? A QoS extension for IPv4 if I'm not taking it 100% wrong.

Does it have to do with the comparison with RSVP protocol too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [what ever happened to ipv5:](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2003/06/what_ever_happened_to_ipv5.html)

> In the late 1970’s, a protocol named ST — The Internet Stream Protocol
>   — was created for the experimental transmission of voice, video, and
>   distributed simulation. Two decades later, this protocol was revised
>   to become ST2 and started to get implemented into commercial projects
>   by groups like IBM, NeXT, Apple, and Sun. Wow did it differ a lot. ST
>   and ST+ offered connections, instead of its connection-less IPv4
>   counterpart. It also guaranteed QoS. ST and ST+, were already given
>   that magical “5″. And now as the Internet clock ticks, our PCs don’t
>   use IPv5. So we’re moving onto 6.